# convert List to a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have created 100 random time series with these code

```
set.seed(1023172)
t<- seq(from=1,to=100,by=1)+10+rnorm(100,sd=7)
lst1 <- lapply(asplit(as.matrix(t), 1), ts, start = 2000, end = 2009)
print(lst1)
```

Then I want to convert this `lst1` from a list to a data frame.
The list looks partly like this:

```
[[1]]
Time Series:
Start = 2000 
End = 2009 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 7.791329 7.791329 7.791329 7.791329 7.791329 7.791329 7.791329 7.791329
 [9] 7.791329 7.791329

[[2]]
Time Series:
Start = 2000 
End = 2009 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 6.355925 6.355925 6.355925 6.355925 6.355925 6.355925 6.355925 6.355925
 [9] 6.355925 6.355925

[[3]]
Time Series:
Start = 2000 
End = 2009 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 8.250623 8.250623 8.250623 8.250623 8.250623 8.250623 8.250623 8.250623
 [9] 8.250623 8.250623

[[4]]
Time Series:
Start = 2000 
End = 2009 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 15.20932 15.20932 15.20932 15.20932 15.20932 15.20932 15.20932 15.20932
 [9] 15.20932 15.20932

[[5]]
Time Series:
Start = 2000 
End = 2009 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 19.12282 19.12282 19.12282 19.12282 19.12282 19.12282 19.12282 19.12282
 [9] 19.12282 19.12282

[[6]]
Time Series:
Start = 2000 
End = 2009 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 14.01422 14.01422 14.01422 14.01422 14.01422 14.01422 14.01422 14.01422
 [9] 14.01422 14.01422

[[7]]
Time Series:
Start = 2000 
End = 2009 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 10.38471 10.38471 10.38471 10.38471 10.38471 10.38471 10.38471 10.38471
 [9] 10.38471 10.38471
```

I have tried `df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(lst1), ncol = max(lengths(lst1)), byrow = TRUE))`, but the data type is always list.
Can anybody help?

Edited on 17.08--
the ultimate goal is to be able to fit `dcc.garch` on this dataset
so it it better to look like:

| year | ts1 | ts2 | ts3 | ts4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

Comment: can you show the format desired for a single element as it is not clear

Answer (score 2):

If we need to convert, perhaps, use `as_tsibble` from `tsibble`

```
library(tsibble)
out <-  lapply(head(lst1), as_tsibble)
```

-ouptut

```
> head(out, 3)
[[1]]
# A tsibble: 10 x 2 [1Y]
   index value
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2000  7.79
 2  2001  7.79
 3  2002  7.79
 4  2003  7.79
 5  2004  7.79
 6  2005  7.79
 7  2006  7.79
 8  2007  7.79
 9  2008  7.79
10  2009  7.79

[[2]]
# A tsibble: 10 x 2 [1Y]
   index value
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2000  6.36
 2  2001  6.36
 3  2002  6.36
 4  2003  6.36
 5  2004  6.36
 6  2005  6.36
 7  2006  6.36
 8  2007  6.36
 9  2008  6.36
10  2009  6.36

[[3]]
# A tsibble: 10 x 2 [1Y]
   index value
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2000  8.25
 2  2001  8.25
 3  2002  8.25
 4  2003  8.25
 5  2004  8.25
 6  2005  8.25
 7  2006  8.25
 8  2007  8.25
 9  2008  8.25
10  2009  8.25
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a way to merge this 100 data frames together, so the 1st column is 2000-2009, then start from the 2nd column are the data frames?

Comment: because my goal is to apply dcc.garch on this data set, it couldn't work when these are lists, I think they need to be 1 data frame or matrix to work

Comment: @Olivia Probably you need a join i.e. `library(purrr);library(dplyr);reduce(out, full_join, by = 'index')`

Comment: Thanks, could you please have a look at this question, this is also from me,  I created this data frame with 1000 time series, but some other error occurred.  Looks like nobody could answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818279/error-in-dimnamesx-dn-length-of-dimnames-2-not-equal-to-array-extent-when

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried as.data.frame()?

```
set.seed(1023172)
t<- seq(from=1,to=100,by=1)+10+rnorm(100,sd=7)
lst1 <- lapply(asplit(as.matrix(t), 1), ts, start = 2000, end = 2009)
df <- as.data.frame(lst1)
```